# Codeigniter Routing not working on Production Environment

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I have codeigniter running fine on my local machine but when I push to the server the routing falls apart. For my set up codeigniter runs from a sub directory named 'secure', so this is the .htaccess file I have created in the 'secure' directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /secure/
RewriteRule ^assets/less/icons/(.*)$ /secure/assets/icons/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The routes file currently looks like this:

```
$route['logout'] = "secure/logout";
$route['passwordReset'] = "secure/PasswordReset";
$route['default_controller'] = 'secure';
```

On my local set up if you were to go to the URL '/secure/dashboard' controller 'Dashboard.php' is correctly called and index initiated. However if I go to the same URL on the server it is trying to call the controller 'Secure.php' instead of 'Dashboard.php'.

I'm not sure what is different between my local environment and the server thats stopping the server ignoring the 'secure' part of the URL, I thought that this line in the .htaccess file should sort out the sub directory: 'RewriteBase /secure/'.

Any feedback is very welcome right now :/

Comment: Well it looks like it is not finding your Dashboard.php controller and it goes to the default which you have defined as secure, so it will be looking for Secure.php. Are you sure you have your folders setup the same as on your localhost? Do you have a Secure.php Controller?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I completely agree with you. I had tested this route on the server '$route['secure/(:any)'] = "$1";' which enabled it to work properly on the server, but consequently broke my local. The structure of both my local and the server are identical, I'm using GIT to sync them.

Comment: Does your production server have an .htaccess file at its root configured differently than your local machine?

Comment: No, the two are set up identically, with the exception of the config, which references the associated domain and database.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got to the bottom of the issue. My server holds a few different environments for development which do not run directly from the http root directory. This was causing the variable $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] to equal '/staging/secure/index.php' instead of '/secure/index.php';, so I simply added the following to the top of the index.php file

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/secure/index.php';
```